# Julia Childs cake recipe featuring Galliano?

Tags: cake

My grandmother remembers watching an episode of Julia Childs’ TV show in which she made a cake that featured a tall bottle of bright yellow liqueur, which we think is probably Galliano. Her recollection is that the episode was highly memorable because Julia was partaking in the liqueur throughout the process.

I’m trying to track down the recipe from that episode but am having trouble finding anything at all about it online. Does anyone know what this recipe or episode was?